# Ionic 4, pegar valor de input

Tags: ionic

Olá, estou tentando pegar o valor de um input em Ionic 4, (sou novo em Ionic), segue meu código:

> Obs.: eu recebo como  resultado: undefined

cadastro.html:

```
<ion-header >
  <!--<ion-toolbar>
      //<ion-title>
        //Ionic Blank
      //</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar> -->
  </ion-header>
<ion-content   >

    <ion-item class="a">  
      <ion-label class="flNome" position="floating">NOME</ion-label>
      <ion-input  [(ngModel)]="title" class="nome" type="text" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
   </ion-content>
```

cadastro.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cadastro',
  templateUrl: './cadastro.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cadastro.page.scss'],
})
export class CadastroPage implements OnInit {
 public title: string;

  constructor(private emailComposer : EmailComposer ) { }
  sendEmail() {
    // var local = $("#slc_Local_Reu").val();
     let email = {
       to: 'dede.miza@gmail.com',
       cc: 'dede.miza@gmail.com',
       
       subject: 'teste',
       body: 'NOME:' + this.title,
       
       isHtml: true
     };
     this.emailComposer.open(email);
 
   }
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente passar um atributo `name` contendo o mesmo nome do seu `Model`.

Ex:

```
 <ion-input  name="title" [(ngModel)]="title" class="nome" type="text" ></ion-input>
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado funcinou!!